# I want to pass an array by value but it seems like it is passed by reference, .map operations on array not giving expected result

Tags: javascript

I have the following code in JS:

```
var result = getData(item, keyName, true); // This function returns a    Key,Value array, of which the value is another array
var arr = [];

for (var count = 0; count < 3; count++) {
    var tmpArray = result.slice(0);
    var newArray = tmpArray.map((res) => {
        var keyEntry = Object.keys(res)[0]; //Gets the key of the entry
        const name = keyName + '_' + count + '.' + keyEntry; //Changes the key so it is prefixed with a certain keyName and count
        res[name] = res[keyEntry]; //use this as the new key
        delete res[keyEntry]; //delete old key
        res[name].splice(1, 0, count);
        return res;
    });
    arr.push(newArray);
}
```

If I print `arr` I get:

```
[ { 'social_profiles_2.social_profiles_1.social_profiles_0.id': [ 'social_profiles', 2, 1, 0, 'id' ] },
  { 'social_profiles_2.social_profiles_1.social_profiles_0.type': [ 'social_profiles', 2, 1, 0, 'type' ] },
  { 'social_profiles_2.social_profiles_1.social_profiles_0.url': [ 'social_profiles', 2, 1, 0, 'url' ] },
  { 'social_profiles_2.social_profiles_1.social_profiles_0.username': [ 'social_profiles', 2, 1, 0, 'username' ] } ]
```

This is however not the result I want, I want one array which consists of 3 key value arrays, one containing the social_profiles_0 stuff, another one containing the social_profile_1 stuff etc.. However in my loop it is concatenating everything in the same array like 'social_profiles_2.social_profiles_1.social_profiles_0.username', I can't seem to understand why...

Edit: To clarify on what it is supposed to do.. This is the object called result which this function takes as input

```
[ { id: [ 'social_profiles', 'id' ] },
{ type: [ 'social_profiles', 'type' ] },
{ url: [ 'social_profiles', 'url' ] },
{ username: [ 'social_profiles', 'username' ] } ]
```

The result should be an array with 3 elements, one with the social_profiles_0, second element social_profiles_1 etc..

Comment: There are lots of things wrong here...`.map` returns a new array so the call to `.splice` is superfluous, `Object.keys(res)[0]` is implementation-defined (the keys in a js object are unordered), you're already using `Object.keys` so I'm confused by the `for...in` loop with the `hasOwnProperty` check (which is what `Object.keys` does), all the deleting, `.splicing`, its hard to see what this is actually supposed to be doing....

Comment: Also there is no such thing as a 'key/value array'. Associative 'arrays' are not arrays, do not implement array methods, do not have O(1) access, etc.

Comment: Hey thanks for your comments, I made some changes to the original post. I added some clarification on the intention + I changed the code according to your comments, it still gives the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems with your code (as I pointed out in the comments). I realize that this isn't code review stack exchange, but I do believe you can't see the problem from all the excess stuff. Here's your original with a line-by-line breakdown:

```
var result = getData(item, keyName, true); // keyName? you don't show us
var arr = [];

for (var count = 0; count < 3; count++) {
  var tmpArray = result.slice(0); // this line is unnecessary, .map makes a copy for you and the zero doesn't do anything
  var newArray = tmpArray.map((res) => {
      var keyEntry = Object.keys(res)[0]; // only works if there's only one key
      const name = keyName + '_' + count + '.' + keyEntry; // const? why?
      res[name] = res[keyEntry]; // mutates the original? you'll mutate it again every time through the for loop
      delete res[keyEntry]; // same problem
      res[name].splice(1, 0, count); // same problem
      return res;
  });
  arr.push(newArray);
}
```

Notice that the copy returned by `.slice` and `.map` is *shallow*, it doesn't clone nested objects/arrays. You'll want to, in general, avoid mutation.

Here's how another might have written the code (ES 6, but you used an arrow function and const, so...)

```
for (var count = 0; count < 3; count++) {
  var array = result.map(res => {
    var keyEntry = Object.keys(res)[0];
    var name = `${keyName}_${count}.${keyEntry}`;

    // here we're returning a new object, no mutation, that has a
    // new array, no mutation (concat also returns a new array)
    return {
      // [name]: [count, ...res[keyEntry]] // updated per the comments
      [name]: res[keyEntry].concat([count]) // re-updated per comments
    };
  });
  arr.push(array);
}
```

Comment: Hey man, I really appreciate the time you took to write this out! It indeed looks way cleaner. The result I get with your code is correct in that the array now contains 3 elements with the proper keys! The value however is empty, so I think there is sonething wrong with res[keyEntry].slice().splice(1, 0, count). Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Kevainzorz no problem. Try doing a `console.log(res[keyEntry]);` before the return statement to see what the value is and adjust accordingly.

Comment: The console.log is outputting [ 'social_profiles', 'type' ] which seems correct to me. As soon as I splice it, the array empties... hmmm

Comment: @Kevainzorz I think it will give you what you want now, see my updated answer.

Comment: @Kevainzorz then your js engine isn't totally caught up yet to the new spec, thats the spread operator `[0, ...[1, 2, 3]]` is the same as `[0, 1, 2, 3]`. Check out the update. You could also use babel to transpile to older syntax https://babeljs.io/

Answer (score 0):

first off, Are you using the .slice(0) to create a shallow copy of the result array?

also I think its due to the line

```
var keyEntry = Object.keys(res)[0];
```

and

```
res[name] = res[keyEntry]
```

When you do that loop you get all the keys of the res obj. But then the first time through the loop you add a new key and then remove the old key. the second time through the loop it grabs that newly created key (NOT the next key in line which is what I think you were intending). You do this loop over and over but you are never moving through the keys, just altering the first key over and over. I think this may be the cause of the weird concatenation.

EDIT:
I am not 100% as to how you want this working but this code snippet is what I think you may help for the first part of the code

```
for (var count = 0; count < 3; count++) {
var newArray = result.map((res) => {
    Object.keys(res).forEach(function(keyName){
        const name = keyName + '_' + count + '.' + keyEntry; 
        res[name] = res[keyEntry];
        delete res[keyEntry]; 
    })
```

Comment: You are correct that the mutation is stacking on each iteration of the loop, but the better solution is to avoid mutation in the first place...